# Variantes de prononciation standard ou régionale ?

Tags: prononciation

Locuteur natif, je connais quelques mots dont la prononciation est parfois différente de celle attendue en lisant le mot (outres les *femme*, *poêle*, *monsieur*).
Je pense notamment à :

> Pharmacie

Prononcé Ph**o**rmacie (assez répandu, je pense)

Et aussi :

> - Circuit
> - Myrtille

Prononcés C**è**rcuit et M**è**rtille sont je pense, moins répandus, mais que je me rappelle avoir entendu au moins pendant mon enfance (j'ai grandi en région lyonnaise).

S'agit-il d'une tendance de prononciation relâchée/"populaire" commune à toute la France ou bien d'une spécificité régionale (pour le deux dernier notamment)?

---

D'autres exemples me sont revenus à l'esprit ce week-end, alors j'ajouterai les mots suivants à ma deuxième liste :

- circulation (*cèrculation*)
- virgule (*vergule*)
- le prénom Virginie (*verginie*)

Encore une fois, ce ne sont peut-être que mes oreilles, mais lorsque j'avais appris à lire, j'avais été surpris du décalage que je percevais entre l'oral et l'écrit sur ses mots. Ce n'était pas le cas pour d'autre mots proches comme : virage, visite etc.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu: Phormacie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il faut distinguer la représentation normalisée des voyelles et la façon dont elles sont réellement prononcées par les locuteurs.

> L'analyse acoustique de productions naturelles révèle que les voyelles notamment ne se regroupent pas en un petit nombre de catégories bien délimitées au plan physique, mais qu'elles couvrent de manière plus ou moins homogène la totalité de l'espace acoustique potentiel. [François Longchamps](http://francois.lonchamp.free.fr/TranscriptionPhonetique/transcriptionPhonetique.pdf)

Il existe donc un continuum entre les voyelles "standard", un peu comme il existe une infinité de nuances entre deux couleurs. Une couleur donnée pourra être qualifiée de bleu par une personne et de vert par une autre.

Il est donc fort possible que le premier [a] de *ph**a**rmacie* puisse se rapprocher d'un [ɔ] mais qu'on n'entende pas toujours ce décalage car le cerveau « corrige » en permanence ce qui est perçu pour le faire correspondre à des mots intelligibles.

On rencontre d'ailleurs souvent ce type décalage avec ***pas*** prononcé ***pô*** [pɔ] et parfois lexicalisé ainsi :

> [ch'ais po si ch'uis claire.](https://forums-enseignants-du-primaire.com/topic/14361-euh-jai-une-tite-question/?tab=comments#comment-181457)

Quant à c**i**rcuit et m**y**rtille, peut-être que le fait que leurs [i] ne portent pas d'accent tonique facilite un rapprochement vers le [ɛ].

Comment: En y repensant, s'agissant de *circuit* et *myrtille* j'avais dû être surpris en lisant ces mots pour la première fois car mon oreille entendait plutot un **è** (bref) qu'un **i**.

Answer (score 0):

Ayant habité un peu partout dans l'hexagone j'ai pu rencontrer de nombreux accents et façon *populaire* de parler.

Mais ô grand jamais je n'ai entendu des personnes prononcer les deux derniers mots listés différemment de leur écriture.

Pour ce qui est de pharmacie, il arrive que certaines régions au parlé nasal (j'entends bien Lyon) transforment certains **a** en **o**.